# FATAL EXCEPTION in Android Runtime AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous, android-asynctask, dalvik

I have this inner class that goes and calls a web service by posting an image up to it that has been saved on the device internal storage:

```
public class OCRScan extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground (String... params) {


            String result = "";

            try{
                String picturePath = params[0];

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://172.16.1.7:8080/OCRService/webresources/read");

                MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                multipartEntity.addPart("image/jpeg", new FileBody(new File (picturePath)));
                post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

                final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);


                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer);
                result= writer.toString();                      

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("FAILED TO CALL SERVICE: ");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (String result) {
            //setResultOnUi(result);
            System.out.println("RESULT RETURNED FROM YOUR SERVICE: \n" + result);

        }

    }
```

I execute this asynchronous task in the parent class like so:

```
OCRScan scan = new OCRScan();
        scan.execute(picturePath);
```

After which I get this "robot-barf" in log cat:

```
06-03 12:10:43.316: D/libEGL(15788): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-03 12:10:43.321: D/libEGL(15788): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-03 12:10:43.326: D/libEGL(15788): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-03 12:10:43.331: E/(15788): Device driver API match
06-03 12:10:43.331: E/(15788): Device driver API version: 23
06-03 12:10:43.331: E/(15788): User space API version: 23 
06-03 12:10:43.331: E/(15788): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Nov 29 14:18:37 KST 2013 
06-03 12:10:43.401: D/OpenGLRenderer(15788): Enabling debug mode 0
06-03 12:10:45.591: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15788): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-03 12:11:03.411: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3891 (DEFAULT_BINARY) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.411: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.411: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3891 (DEFAULT_BINARY) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.416: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3891 (DEFAULT_BINARY) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.416: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addPart
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10394: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;.notNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-03 12:11:03.416: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3892 (DEFAULT_TEXT) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.416: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.416: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3891 (DEFAULT_BINARY) in Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.421: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.421: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10200: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.create (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.421: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.421: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10201: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.create (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.421: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.421: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.426: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10394: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;.notNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-03 12:11:03.426: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
06-03 12:11:03.426: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10394: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;.notNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-03 12:11:03.426: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.426: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.parse, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10205: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
06-03 12:11:03.426: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.426: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve static method 10394: Lorg/apache/http/util/Args;.notNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-03 12:11:03.426: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
06-03 12:11:03.426: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.getCharset, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.getCharset
06-03 12:11:03.426: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10203: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.getCharset ()Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;
06-03 12:11:03.426: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.431: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)
06-03 12:11:03.431: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.getMimeType, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.getMediaType
06-03 12:11:03.431: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10204: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.getMimeType ()Ljava/lang/String;
06-03 12:11:03.431: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.431: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.getMimeType, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.getMimeType
06-03 12:11:03.431: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10204: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.getMimeType ()Ljava/lang/String;
06-03 12:11:03.431: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.431: I/dalvikvm(15788): Could not find method org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.getMimeType, referenced from method org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.getSubType
06-03 12:11:03.431: W/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10204: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;.getMimeType ()Ljava/lang/String;
06-03 12:11:03.431: D/dalvikvm(15788): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
06-03 12:11:03.431: W/dalvikvm(15788): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e1a700)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.deangrobler.imageocr.MainActivity$OCRScan.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:174)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at com.deangrobler.imageocr.MainActivity$OCRScan.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-03 12:11:03.436: E/AndroidRuntime(15788):    ... 4 more
```

And then the app crashes.. Any help with this would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You have a probleme in line 299 , caused by org.apache.http.entity.ContentType , can you check thid issue??

Comment: I can see that yes. But that's nothing related to my code, that's a 3rd party apache library. If others have experienced this with the apache library, then I can take it further with them, I'm just making sure this then isn't something I am doing wrong in MY code..

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project and rebuild?

Comment: The classs `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType` is missing at runtime.

Comment: I think that the Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType doesn't exist n your lib or your configuration is wrong .

Comment: check your import and try to clean and rebuild your project. and check
your project->rightclick->properties->order and export-> version checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly download  httpmime, httpcore and httpclient library from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and placed in your project /libs folder.

Comment: So.. turned out I had httpmine but didn't have client or core.. go figure. Thanks!